# Class name problem on laravel 5.8 with Request->input

Tags: php, laravel, web-scraping, homestead, laravel-5.8

I'm trying to follow a tutorial to create a simple web scraper [here](https://webmobtuts.com/backend-development/building-a-simple-scraping-website-with-php-laravel-part3-article-display/) using Laravel, but symfony threw a "Class name must be a valid object or string" error on line 49. In phpstorm it did gave me a light warning of field accessed with magic method on $website->title

I've tried to declare $title as a public var in my App/Website.php but it still gave me this error.

here's the snippet of the code with error

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            'title'=>'required',
            'url'=>'required',
            'logo'=>'required'
        ]);

        $website = new Website();

        $website->title = new $request->input('title');

        $website->url = $request->input('url');

        $website->logo = $this->uploadFile('logo', public_path('uploads/'), $request)["filename"];

        $website->save();

        return redirect()->route('websites.index');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
```

and here's my App/Website Class:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Website extends Model
{
    protected $table = "website";
    public $title;
    /**
     * @var array|string|null
     */
    public $url;
    public $logo;

}
```

It should've saved the title, url and logo to a sql db i named scraper but it keeps throwing this error. Please help.

Edit 2: <strike>I apologize it seems i copied the code shown by symfony, my actual WebsiteController is like this</strike> copied wrong code again, here's the actual actual code:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            'title'=>'required',
            'url'=>'required',
            'logo'=>'required'
        ]);

        $website = new Website();

        $website->title = new $request->input('title');

        $website->url = $request->input('url');

        $website->logo = $this->uploadFile('logo', public_path('uploads/'), $request)["filename"];

        $website->save();

        return redirect()->route('websites.index');
    }
```

Comment: Try `$website->title = $request->input('title')`. There shouldn't be any new `request` object creation.

Comment: @Haru $website = Website::find($id);

        $website->title = $request->input('title');

is my actual code, the one above is shown by symfony.

Comment: Could you update your question accordingly?

Comment: Updated accordingly.

Comment: I'm lost. There's still  `new $request->input('title')`. Get rid of that **new** keyword and you'll be fine. Where's that `Website::find($id)` you mentioned earlier in the comment?

Comment: @Haru ehem, my bad, it seems trying to debug this combined with my actual work in the office fried my brain. Will try to remove the new keyword.

Comment: Let us know if it helped.

Comment: @Haru it worked but now it gave me a SQLSTATE error:   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'title' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `website` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2019-08-20 07:29:42, 2019-08-20 07:29:42))

Comment: Good. I'd put that as an answer, but Karan did that a bit after my commentary. Consider giving him an approval. That message explains everything you need to know. Check if the request has a `title` property (or if it's empty). Another thing you might want to do is to put a default title value in the website model migration (it might be something like `$table->text('title')->nullable()`).

Comment: Thank you @Haru wish i could've given an upvote or something for your help, but sadly stackoverflow doesn't really do things like that.
Anyway, thank you very much for your time.

Comment: No problem. I'm glad I could help. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here `new` should not be there ,`$website->title = new $request->input('title');` , You are not making object from any class. i guess you miss type.

and you can still get your data by just `$request->title;` i prefer this because it short your code and still readable.

Do it like below

`$website->title = $request->input('title');`

Or

`$website->title = $request->title;`
and also for saving data into db you don't need to declare variable.

simply in model add protected `$fillable=['title','url','logo'];`

or if you using `save()` method you don't even need to add `$fillable`